# Forecasting with empirical copulas

Tags: forecasting, copula, out-of-sample

I estimated the beta copula with 3 variable time series. Now I'd like to make forecasts to evaluate the out-of-sample performance of my model. I know 2 of the 3 variables and I have the dependence structure (copula density), how can I predict the third, unknown variable?

In general, how does one make predictions with copula models?

thanks

Comment: If you use R programs.  Have a look at `copulaReg`. there are many function in R.